# jQuery 1.4 change event bug in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-1.4

I have this simple select:

```
<select name="zlecenia_index_icpp" id="items_per_page">  
    <option value="10">10</option>  
    <option value="25" selected="selected">25</option>  
    <option value="50">50</option>  
</select>
```

and on it there's:

```
$('#items_per_page').change(function(){  
    var controller_action = this.name.replace(/_/g, '/');  
    location.href = config.base_url + '/' + controller_action + '/'+this.value;  
});
```

It used to work in jQuery 1.3, but in 1.4 the change event is fired as soon as I click on the select box. Is there any solution besides going back to 1.3?

---

This really seems to be a bug and it has been reported to jQuery:

http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5869

There has been a patch applied and will be part of jQuery 1.4.1.

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/435772e29b4ac4ccfdefbc4045d43f714e153381

Comment: I reported the bug here: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5869

Comment: Any particular version of IE?

Comment: I have seen it on IE 7 with XHTML 1.0 Strict in my case.

Comment: Interesting, that it only fires
1) after releasing the mouse button
2) Only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's fix for this bug:
http://github.com/mcurry/jquery/commit/a293f5938eb9efd41158b948f487672d43b7c820

Hopefully it'll get into 1.4.1

Answer (score 3):

From http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14

> `change` and `submit` events
>   normalized (Change Documentation,
>   Submit Documentation)
>
> The change and submit events work
>   reliably across browsers for both
>   normal and live events. We override
>   the normal change and submit events in
>   Internet Explorer and replace them
>   with events that work identically to
>   the other browsers.

OK, this looks like it's a bug, either in IE or JQuery.

What's causing the problem is the selected="selected" attribute on the option is causing the change event to fire before any mouse event occurs. My guess is, it's a weirdness/bug with IE as it appears that it does not set the selected element UNTIL it is visible, thus causing the change even to fire upon the initial dropdown. I say it's a bug in IE because if I call window.event.cancelBubble, the event handler doesn't fire at all.

That's really weird.

The workaround is to remove the selected attribute.

Comment: it's definitely a bug in jQuery 1.4, adding an onchange attribute to the select works just fine in IE regardless of any selected attributes on child options.

Comment: Yeah, it was a bug that was fixed in 1.41.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's supposed to work this way, but you are accessing `this.value` and `this.name` in the same callback. I would assume `this` refers to `event.currentTarget`, which in this case is the SELECT element.

In that case, `this.value` will be undefined, but you can try using `$(this).val();` instead.

Did you try consoling out the variables?

Comment: Everything's been working for a year with 1.3, it's only a problem with jQuery 1.4 in IE.

Comment: What does this.value and this.name give you?

Comment: this.value is the selected option's value, which is select's value; this.name is select's name.

Comment: It is not related to this.value or this.name, my code doesn't contain any of those references and it still happens.  By the way this only happens on the first open for me, every other open of the select box works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am still getting a similar issue even with 1.4.1.

Using the example below:

1. Select a value from the select list - an alert appears (Correct).
2. Click the Change link - select list resets to 0 (Correct).
3. Click the Select list - an alert appears. (Wrong)

The alert in the third step does not appear in 1.3.2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dropDownList1').bind('change',function(){ alert("changed"); });

        $('#btnChange').click(function(){
            $('#dropDownList1')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        });
    });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <select id="dropDownList1">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>

        <a href="#" id="btnChange">Change</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It only happens after using the 'Change' link and even then it happens only once (ie7).

Answer (score -4):

You can use the [blur()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur) event of jquery. Perhaps something like this:

```
var defaultValue = 10;

$('#items_per_page').blur(function(){  
    if ($("#items_per_page").val() == defaultValue)
        return; //The value wasn't changed, so return.
    var controller_action = this.name.replace(/_/g, '/');  
    location.href = config.base_url + '/' + controller_action + '/'+this.value;  
});
```

Comment: This has the same effect as the change event.  I think the key to it working for you is that you have included an interrupt.