# Why does my javascript function not work in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my JavaScript function. It's nested in a document.ready function()

```
$(".bim").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
    str += $(this).next().text() + "_";
        });
    str = str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
    alert(str);
});
```

It works fine in Firefox and Chrome.

It DOES NOT work with IE8 and IE6

I'm very new to javascript and help would be much appreciated

Comment: What does "it DOES NOT" work mean? It gives no alert/popup? Does it alert/popup but with no message?

Comment: which version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: no alert at all. Debuggin it(f12 in IE8) doesn't even fire the .change(function)
very odd

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery 1.4.2 which fixed several issues with the `.change()` method for IE

See [Related issue](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/change-event-bugs-in-ie)
Also here on  [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093121/jquery-1-4-change-event-bug-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Internet Explorer does not support the `:checked` pseudo class (and neither does Sizzle IIRC).</strike>

*Internet Explorer doesn't support `:checked:`, but as **bobince** pointed out, it will fall back to Sizzle, which does in fact support `:checked`.*

What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: Sizzle does. Normally when a browser's `querySelectorAll()` doesn't support a particular piece of syntax (or the syntax is just wrong, or a non-standard extension), jQuery catches the resulting exception and falls back to using Sizzle instead.